# disable spring security for specific path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I know this has been answered before, but I cant seem to make it work:

I have a custom JWT filter and trying to permit unauthenticated calls for a specific rest path:

Here is the code in WebConfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and().
            sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/documents/fax").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilterBean(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

If I call fax path, I end up in the JWT Filter

I also tried with this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/documents/fax**");
}
```

which gives this in the log:

```
2017-08-10 12:32:06.245  INFO 12258 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/documents/fax**'], []
```

but with same result. Finally I tried with both block of code, same result.

I also have this as annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

I tried without the EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation, not working
Thank you for any help...

Comment: "If I call fax path, I end up in the JWT Filter" - I don't see why this is an error.

Comment: I am trying to not go through security for the given path...